# Chrome Tab creation Limit to 3 only?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

I found that in my code snippet
no matter how large the number set, the chrome tab creation will only limit to 3 per time.

Anyone know why and solve this issue?

```
var number=xxx;
for (i=0;i<number; ++i){
      chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://" + url});
    };
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't create so many tabs (at once)? Perhaps creating tabs on a delay or on a user interaction ..

Comment: there is a input user box to enter the number of tab want to create...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background.js can create > 10 tabs, but in popup.js or in contentscript.js , it cannot
I try it~

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit of tabs creation.

I tested it in my background.js and i created over 10 tabs.

Maybe you have another extension that limits the tabs?

Where do you write your code?

Comment: you are right, background.js can create > 10 tabs, but in popup.js or in contentscript.js , it cannot~